# Replacing usernames with links in Javascript with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match usernames within a string like:

```
"user: hi, has anyone seen user today user"
```

The cases to match:

- substring is the first word trailing a space, in the middle surrounded by spaces or the last and leading a space
- Following characters are allowed to trail the word but not returned as a result: ":;,"

The following matches all the cases but returns unwanted spaces and characters (I only want to replace usernames):

```
/(^(user)[\s|:|;|,])|(\s(user)[\s|:|;|,]?\s)|(\s(user))/gi
```

In the end I want to replace only username with links.

EDIT: Note that the username can't be matched if it's part of url or other string, except cases when special characters are trailing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending upon how transparent you want it to be to users (or what your eventual goal is), you may consider requiring someone to put a symbol (such as `@`) before a user name, so that they can elect whether or not to have a link to the user...

Aside from that, your expression has several potential errors: character classes (denoted by `[]`) treat nearly all characters literally, including `|`, the entire alternation syntax makes the third alternation (`(\s(user))`) into something that will allow matches to `userSmith` or `userJones` and not just `user` - which is something I think you specifically want to disallow...

I think you are asking for something like this:

```
(^|\s)(user)(?=[:;,\s]|$)
```

this breaks down to:

```
(^|\s)      # either assert that this is the beginning, or capture a whitespace character; capture into back-reference #1
(user)      # capture the username 'user' exactly 
(?=         # look-ahead to verify that the following CAN be matched
   [:;,\s]  #    one character that is      :  ;  ,  <or whitespace>
   |        #     -OR-
   $        #    the end of the string
)           # end look-ahead
```

However, there are a few cases that you might want to consider. By not allowing several types of punctuation after the username, you will exclude results from strings like: `Let me know if you see user.`, `have you seen user?` or `I really like user!` - the rejection for URLs should already be accomplished by requiring whitespace (or the beginning of the string) before `user` - not allowing such punctuation afterwards will reject some cases I think you will want to match. You could simply add in this extra punctuation:

```
(^|\s)(user\b)(?=[;:,.?!)"\s]|$)
```

But I would suggest something more like the following (removing the following-punctuation requirement):

```
(^|\s)(user\b)
```

I've put all three suggestions on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWVWz/1/), to show you what you get and allow you to put some of your own strings in.

Which ever way you prefer, these expressions would be used in a find-replace wherein you would replace the whitespace consumed before the user's name with itself in the replace expression:

```
source.replace(/(^|\s)(user\b)/gi, '$1<a href="/linkToProfile?n=$2">$2</a>')
```

Though I'm pretty sure I answered the question, please let me know if there are cases you specified that aren't covered!

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for `\b` which means "word boundary":

```
/\buser\b/gi
```

Edit after your comment:

You can easily add the required characters after your username with a lookahead:

```
/\buser(?=[:;,\s]|$)/gi
```

Unfortunately you can't do the same for restrictions on the characters before the username because Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds. But perhaps this is good enough for your needs?

If not, as a workaround you can capture the characters that must occur before the string and replace them with themselves.

Comment: Except that a capture group should be added around `user`.

Comment: This doesn't really work as it also matches false positives like "www.user.com" which isn't desired (this is actually the reason why I'm trying to come up with a new regex)

Answer (score 3):

```
str.replace(
  /(^|\s)(user)(?=[\s:;,]|$)/gi, // look-ahead credits: Code Jockey
  "$1replacement$3"
);
```

Comment: I added the dollar at the end of regex, you probably forgot it in the one cited in the question.

Comment: This seems to work ok, but fails with following strings: "user user user," and "user"

Comment: The `"user"` is your fault (I just took your old regex and changed parentheses, it does not work there as well). Maybe you could change it to `/(^|\s)(user)([\s|:|;|,]?\s|$)/gi`, I don't know if such thing works. The `"user user user"` example is harder, since they probably overlap and are not allowed. Run it two times in a chain (first run should do "replacement user replacement", the second run does the middle user. Not that it is elegant but it should do the trick...

Comment: But I think what you really should do instead of this crazy magic is to use `/\buser\b/gi` and use a function as a replacement argument to `replace` where you should programmatically explore the surroundings of the match (you get the position and the whole string in arguments), and there you can simply check if this word is fine to replace or not and return "user" or "replacement" accordingly.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted but I still can't get it work: the above one and all the ones I have tried are losing spaces when doing replacement inline. Ideas?

Comment: The one I suggested in the comment above does not lose spaces for me (tried in node). So use it (it's also shorter) and running it twice does it for all cases you presented. I'm going to edit it in the answer itself, it's more correct one.

Comment: Yep, it seems to work if used couple of time in a row. Just a small correction: to match "user user user," (notice the trailing comma) I needed make the last \s optional (/(^|\s)(user)([\s|:|;|,]?\s?|$)/gi)

Comment: I doubt if it's ever needed, then. Maybe it should be `/(^|\s)(user)([\s|:|;|,]|$)/gi`. Even `|`s are not needed inside `[]` so in fact, to be correct, it should be `/(^|\s)(user)([\s:;,]|$)/gi`

Comment: @jorde - you're sacrificing 50 pts of your reputation for something that doesn't work? I'm pretty sure my answer satisfies your need and addresses all the concerns raised in the comments above... Sorry it took so long!

Comment: @herby this expression does satisfy the originally specified need, though it does have to be run twice - use a look-ahead instead of consuming the `[\s:;,]|$` -- it will allow a single run! Also consider if the user name `user` is at the end of a sentence or used possessively (as in `I talked with user.` or ` I looked at user's profile...`) -- both are ignored...

Comment: @Code Jockey: Thanx for look-ahead (I am not a regex guru, I just use what I am used to, so I did not know it existed in the first place :-) ), as for what characters to use, it's jorde's business, he will probably add a few in the meantime...

Comment: @Code Jockey: Sorry, this is my first bounty and I just needed a working solution. In fact I forgot to award the +50 earlier (didn't notice that you need actually click the icon separate from right answer). Your answer was really impressive and worked really well without hacks, so there you have it. Thanks fot both

Comment: Edit: I see it now: [The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty). It should award about 24 hours after you placed the bounty. Regardless, I am mostly concerned that you get a useful answer, when such an answer is available. Occasionally people leave this site before a good answer comes in and never come back - that's a shame! We have a good community here!

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "user: hi, has anyone seen user, today user";
var username = "user";
var rx = new RegExp("(^|\\s)(" + username + ")([\\s:;,]|$)", "gi");

/* 'user: hi, has anyone seen <a href="…">user</a>, today <a href="…">user</a>' */
var result = input.replace(rx, function (match, paren1, username, paren3) {
  return paren1 + '<a href="…">' + username + '<\/a>' + paren3;
});
```

`(^|\s)` and `(\s|$)` instead of `\b` prevents the leading `user:` from matching, and works with non-ASCII user names (`\b` matches any boundary created by characters not matched by `[A-Za-z0-9_]`; see [ECMAScript Edition 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), section 15.10.2.6 "Assertion").

You need to escape the `username` *variable* value if it contains any [`RegExp`-special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions), and the `username` *argument* value if it contains any URI- or (X)HTML-special characters. For example:

```
// …
username = username.replace(/[\]\\^$*+?.(){}[]/g, "\\$&");
var rx = new RegExp("(^|\\s)(" + username + ")([\\s:;,]|$)", "gi");

var result = input.replace(rx, function (match, paren1, username, paren3) {
  return (paren1 + '<a href="…/' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '">'
    + username.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    + '<\/a>' + paren3);
});
```

(See also `jsx.regexp.escape` in [JSX:regexp.js](http://pointedears.de/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JSX&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fregexp.js).)

You may want to enhance this depending on what you consider to be a "url" etc.  See [RFC 3986, Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B), for a Regular Expression to match URIs.